# Fewer system types for Actions on Google than in Dialogflow?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I've been studying Dialogflow and have now started studying Actions on Google with the desire to build assistant actions.  As I read about the system data types found in the [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#system_types) Actions Builder I seem to see only a few types:

- Date
- Time
- Date/Time
- Number

while when I look in Dialogflow and look at [System Entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-entities) I seem to see many more than those exposed by Actions on Google.

Currently, I have a need to recognize a person's name.  An example phrase would be:

> I'd like to book the class taught by `Brandon`

In Dialogflow, I'd define the intent parameter as being of `@sys.person`.  I don't seem to have that option in Actions on Google and would appear to have to build my own data type.

Is there a reason that the rich set of system defined data types for Dialogflow aren't exposed for Actions on Google using the Actions Builder?   What is the recommended approach to define a type that would otherwise be a system type in Dialogflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest reason, likely, is that they were either sparsely used or too complicated to be effective. For example, `@sys.person` is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities) as

> **Common** given names, last names or their combinations

(Emphasis mine.) But there are plenty of people with "uncommon" names, that would not be captured, so it is not actually useful in a number of cases. A surprisingly large number of cases in reality.

Under Actions Builder, you can create a [custom type](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#custom_types) that either enumerates the possible values (which would be best for your example) or free-form text. (Or combine the two.)

If you are concerned with needing to update your Action with new names, it may make sense to make a generic type and then have the values for that type [updated at runtime](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#runtime_type_overrides). This can make for a much more dynamic and flexible Action.